# What is the role of returnUrl in Angular

Tags: angular

Can anyone explain me this code:

```js
this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
```

What does this code do. What is `returnUrl`? I searched Angular docs but couldn't find more about it where is it narrated.

Edit   Added after getting this much help and based on my understanding::
ReturnUrl is a programmer defined queryparem
ReturnUrl is used to make a user navigate to the url he was trying to access after login. For example at first the user might be trying to navigate to dashboard but he will not be allowed as it is auth guarded. but on login the returnUrl query parames is used to help the user navigate back to the dashboard.

Comment: its a query parameter. its to say: "Browser please navigate the user to `/login?returnUrl=<state.url content>` "

Answer (score 3):

`returnUrl` is not documented in the Angular documentation, since it's defined as a `queryParam`. It can just be **anything** you pass in there.

It will then be part of the URL like:

```
foo://example.com:8042/over/there?returnUrl=login
\_/   \______________/\_________/ \_____________/ 
 |           |            |            |
scheme    authority      path        query
```

In your case: it will be used as a reference where to direct the user to when the person is (not) able to login. `state.url` is most likely a string and `queryParams` are handled as strings, so adding `returnUrl=true` will result in a stringified true: `'true'`.

Another example:

```js
// Navigate to /results?page=1
this.router.navigate(['/results'], { queryParams: { page: 1 } });
```

Here it will only show the results of the first page. See Angular documentation [about queryParams inside UrlCreationOptions](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlCreationOptions#queryParams).

Comment: but how does it work when i tell returnUrl as true.Can you please enlighten me

Comment: what is state.url

Comment: @somanraj I updated my answer. See 'In your case...'

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the Component that loads on `/login` after Login has been successful might need it to redirect the user to the url that is specified in `returnUrl`.

A `redirectUrl` is generally used on Login Screens as a redirection route after successful login.

So consider this:

Your app has a lot of different screens that load as a result of navigation to a lot of different routes. Some of these routes could be protected and might need the user to sign-in before they can access these routes.

So some logic(generally in a Route Guard) might check if the user is logged in or not, when trying to navigate to these routes. And when the user is not logged in, they might navigate the user to the `/login` route that loads up a `LoginComponent`. At this point, you might need to be aware of the route that the user was trying to navigate to. And you can let the `LoginComponent` know about it, by passing it as a `queryParam`.

Comment: what does returnurl false means

Comment: where is it inside angular framework defined@SiddAjmera

Comment: @somanraj `returnUrl` isn't something specific to Angular. It's just another query param that you can specify to the Angular Router. Consider this a some sort of a metadata that the Angular Router could provide to the Component so that the Component is mindful of the route that the user was intending to navigate to.

Comment: But in the above example I can toggle the metadata of returnUrl to false or true right.But what does that mean.I am still not fully clear in this concept.Can you please tell me more about that,I would be greatful to you

Comment: what is state.url hold

Comment: `returnUrl` has nothing to do with angular, but only and only with the application where this was used

Comment: In the `router.navigate` call, the `queryParams` option can accept any object. `returnUrl` was just randomly picked by the one who wrote the code snippet